# Find Out the First Record that Above a Certain Value

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a derived table with columns like:

- email (main identifier)
- transaction_time
- amount

How to look for customers (identified by email) based on the `amount > 500` for the first transaction in PostgreSQL?

Note: This is used in a sub query that is used to filter the main table.

Comment: Can you add sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 2):

Below solution will be more portable that `DISTINCT ON` which is Postgres specific. Use `row_number()` to enumerate the rows and get all distinct customers (identified by email) that have their first transaction amount greater than 500.

*Edit:* I've included three ways to achieve the same result. Choose whichever you prefer.

**First approach - using `row_number()`**

```
select 
  distinct email
from (
  select 
    email, 
    amount,
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY email ORDER BY transaction_time) AS rn
  from <derived_table_here>
  ) t
where
  rn = 1
  and amount > 500
```

**Second approach - using `DISTINCT ON`**

```
select 
  email 
from (
  select distinct on (email) 
    email, 
    amount
  from <derived_table_here>
  order by email, transaction_time
  ) t 
where amount > 500
```

**Third approach - using `NOT EXISTS`**

```
select 
  email
from <derived_table_here> t1
where 
  amount > 500 
  and not exists(
    select 1 
    from <derived_table_here> t2 
    where 
      t1.email = t2.email 
      and t1.transaction_time > t2.transaction_time
    )
```

I find the third method the most portable, since MySQL for instance does not support window functions, AFAIK. This is just in case of switching between databases in the future - less work for you.

---

Tested on below sample:

```
      email      |      transaction_time      | amount
-----------------+----------------------------+--------
 first@mail.com  | 2016-09-26 19:01:15.297251 |    400 -- 1st, amount < 500
 first@mail.com  | 2016-09-26 19:01:19.160095 |    500
 first@mail.com  | 2016-09-26 19:01:21.526307 |    550
 second@mail.com | 2016-09-26 19:01:28.659847 |    600 -- 1st, amount > 500
 second@mail.com | 2016-09-26 19:01:30.292691 |    200
 second@mail.com | 2016-09-26 19:01:31.748649 |    300
 third@mail.com  | 2016-09-26 19:01:38.59275  |    200 -- 1st, amount < 500
 third@mail.com  | 2016-09-26 19:01:40.833897 |    100
 fourth@mail.com | 2016-09-26 19:01:51.593279 |    501 -- 1st, amount > 500
```

Comment: To my understanding applying a where clause could disqualify first transactions, whereas we can't disqualify first transactions regardless of they amount at the beginning, but instead mark them as first.

Comment: yeah I missed what you where doing at first and interpreted it in different ways. but there is still a better way in 1 query

Comment: I'm not saying this is the best solution, you are free to add yours :-) I'd love to see that, it's just the first that came into my mind.

Comment: + 1 I read the question differently than you because the OP states for the first transaction in PostgresSQL... What does that mean? First transaction in the table, First transaction that has reach 500???, OP is still not perfectly clear but I am on board with your interpretation at this point because it would be a more typical use case.  And I learned about PostgresSql DISTINCT ON() method that is a new one to my by standard ANSI syntax you wouldn't think that would produce the result but I did test it myself to learn.  Last method not represented is a self join. but you got this well covered.

Answer (score 0):

This should probably do it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (email) *
FROM t
WHERE amount > 500
ORDER BY email, transaction_time
```

It will return the first transaction (with respect to `transaction_time`) for each email.

Comment: Matt, please look into DISTINCT ON.

Answer (score 0):

another option:

```
select * from t t1
where amount > 500
and not exists
(select 1 from t t2 where t1.email=t2.email and t1.transaction_time>t2.transaction_time)
```

Answer (score 0):

LEFT SELF JOIN METHOD

```
  SELECT t1.*
  FROM
      ExmapleTable t1
      LEFT JOIN ExmapleTable t2
      ON t1.Email = t2.Email
      AND t2.transaction_time < t1.transaction_time
  WHERE
      t1.Amount >= 500
      AND t2.Email IS NULL
  ;
```

http://rextester.com/XRQTX2627